# Вопрос по правильности организации DTO c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, архитектура, asp.net-web-api, dto

Работаю с внешним API, ответ приходит такой:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "last_updated_at": "2023-06-23T10:15:59Z"
    },
    "data": {
        "AED": {
            "code": "AED",
            "value": 3.67306
        },
        "AFN": {
            "code": "AFN",
            "value": 91.80254
        },
        "ALL": {
            "code": "ALL",
            "value": 108.22904
        },
        "AMD": {
            "code": "AMD",
            "value": 480.41659
        },
        "...": "150+ more currencies"
    }
}
```

Я сделал модель Currency:

```
/// <summary>
/// Класс представляющий валюту
/// </summary>
public class Currency
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Код валюты
    /// </summary>
    public string Code { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Курс валюты
    /// </summary>
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

И сделал DTO модели:

```
/// <summary>
/// Класс представляющий ответ внешнего api
/// </summary>
public class ExternalApiResponseDto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Данные ответа
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, Currency> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Вопрос: правильно ли я выделил модель и DTO? Не совсем еще могу правильно определять. Второй вопрос: если я в DTO хочу добавить свойство Meta, я для этого должен создать класс с одним свойством даты, я этот класс в папке DTO создаю, или лучше внутри этого же класса ExternalAPIResponse создавать? И это должен быть класс, или лучше Record?
В ответ я должен отправлять:

```
{
  "code": "RUB", // код валюты
  "value": 90.50 // текущий курс относительно доллара, округлен до 2 знаков
}
```

Для него я тоже создаю DTO, или нет смысла, так как это почти то же самое что и модель, не считая округление курса?

Comment: ИМХО, DTO - это Объект передачи данных, то есть некий объект/структура объектов, которые в себе только что-то хранят и предназначены исключительно для передачи данных между устройствами и др. То есть, **все** ваши классы, это по сути DTO, которые описывают JSON. Ну а модель в свою очередь, то некий объект со своей логикой, который что-то получает и на основе этого что-то отдает (например "Модель по работе с API, которая имеет методы "Получить курс валюты", "Перевести на валюту по курсу" и так далее.

Comment: Что касается второго вопроса - полностью всю структуру JSON пропишите в одном классе, даже если не используете (или сервер не дает) вам этих данных. Сериализаторы довольно умные, и они просто оставят эти значения как `NULL`. Тут подстраивайтесь под сервер, какой он ответ дает, такой и DTO у вас должен быть. Если сервер дает в одном API один ответ, а в другом совершенно другое, то тут уже да, 2 разных класса, с разными данными (может даже пересекающимися).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ но это же можно было ответом?

Comment: @aepot Вот у нас с вами есть выбор, отвечать или нет. Есть выбор, хотим мы данный ответ в своем профиле или нет. Есть выбор комментарий или ответ. Есть выбор, развернуто или нет. Я этим выбором и пользуюсь. Ну не хочу я отвечать на что-то подобное, ну не хочу. Как смотрю не хотят и другие, только я вот хотяб комментарий подобный оставляю. Так что, давайте не будете говорит, на что мне отвечать, а на что нет, ок? Я тут не ради ответов и репутации. Хотите, прям копируйте мой коммент (любой) и вставляйте в ответ, я не против, но сам делать это без желания написания развернутого ответа, не буду.